# rotate text on Z axe in illustrator cs5

Tags: adobe-illustrator

should be a simple thing but can find the way to rotate text in z axe in illustrator ? I dont want to make it a 3d text just rotate it on the Z axe to make it fit in perpective (one word on the left black line and second word on right black line)

Tks

Comment: Illustrator has no tool or reference for a z axis other than in `Effect > 3D`. Illustrator is not now, and has never been, a 3D tool.

Comment: k, i saw a lot of logo with text rotate in z axe maybe done in other soft ?any cue about other soft i have all adobe product. And Tks

Comment: There are a ton of 3D apps out there. Photoshop *Extended* also has some 3D capabilities.

Comment: Rotating things in space does not require a 3D tool. They are just simple projections after all

Answer (score 5):

In addition to DLev's answer, you can also play with 3D Effects like 3D Rotate or 3D Extrude (via **Effects > 3D**)

[image: 3D rotate effects]

The 1st xyz cube is generated by applying the 3D rotate effect to each letter, using the Isometric presets for rotation, but adding a wee bit of Perspective.

The 2nd xyz cube is generating by extruding a square and using the Map Art option using x,y,z as symbols.

Perhaps another tool to explore is the Perspective Grid Tool (along with Perspective Selection Tool):

[image: perspective tool]

Have a play, these are fun to use :)

Comment: This answer helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate rotating on the Z axis by using the Free Distort tool. Adobe seemingly hasn't updated the features in this tool in about 10 years, so it's still very rudimentary and clunky, but it could work depending on the look you need to accomplish.

Edit: Here's some screenshots showing what I mean.

1) Start with simple text (can be editable, no need for outlines). Make a copy, use Free Distort tool to create faux-rotation on Z-axis.
[image]

2) Copy/paste original text as many times as desired, repeat Free Distort, but with more "depth" each time.

[image]

Again, it's a "hacky" way to get a (possible?) desired result.

Comment: Please explain. I'm curious as to what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I wasn't thinking of "perspective" I was thinking of rotation :)

Comment: I hear ya, I guess in this example, they're one and the same. If you could put a rod horizontally through the middle of the word "Testing" and rotate it (top away from you), you'd pretty much get the same effect as what you see above.

Answer (score 1):

When you mean Z axis, the other answers make sense. It's close to be perspective. Maybe this can be another step that can be used with the other suggested solutions.

So I'll post this in case the axis is misnamed or you need something that can easily be done with the "free transform" tool in Photoshop or the rotation tool in Illustrator.

---

Use Free Transform on your shape for Photoshop (command + T). In Illustrator, simply select the rotating tool after selecting your shape.

There is a circle in the middle of the shape now. Drag that circle where you want your shape rotational base point to be (sorry, I don't know how to name this!) On my example below, I moved it on the lower left corner.

Then do your rotation as you normally would.

If you don't want to rotate a shape by the center, that's one trick to do it.

[image: How to rotate a shape in Photoshop and Illustrator]

Comment: Just fyi.. this user actually posted an answer to their own question (then asked for it to be deleted.) They ended up using skew.... which is a far cry different than "rotation on the z"

Comment: It's actually very good you point out the keyword "skew" in this page with your comment! I couldn't really figure out what was a Z axis rotation quite frankly besides using that kind of transform. But when I search online for script help (for example), I'm always happy someone asked a question with terms I would use myself since I don't even know how to call what I want. I'm sure I would make some dev facepalm if they'd see my search keywords! That's why this kind of question shouldn't be deleted ;)